# Can I map over a list and expand it at the same time in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a list of Tuple-2 like this:

```
val stuff = List( ("!thing","value"), ("otherthing","value") )
```

I want to pass over this list and create objects from the contents like this:

```
val processed = stuff.map{ case (label, value) => 
  if(label.startsWith("!"))
    BigThing(label.tail,value) // extends trait Thing
  else
    LittleThing(label,value) . // extends trait Thing
}
```

So far so good.  Now the question...

While I'm mapping over these tuples, if the label starts with "!", I also want to create a `Bonus(label.tail)` object (also extends trait Thing) and add this object to the resulting list.  This means that an input list of n items may result a list of >n items out.  What's the most streamlined functional solution to this?

The final output desired is an expanded list of Thing.  So the example above would theoretically produce (order unimportant):

```
List( BigThing("thing","value"), Bonus("thing"), LittleThing("otherthing","value") )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `flatMap` for this:

```
val processed = stuff.flatMap { case (label, value) =>
  if (label.startsWith("!"))
    List(BigThing(label.tail, value), Bonus(label.tail))
  else
    List(LittleThing(label, value))
}
```

Result:

```
List(BigThing(thing,value), Bonus(thing), LittleThing(otherthing,value))
```

Comment: Checking this as the best answer. Actually the foldLeft answer below worked better for my particular usage, but the flatMap is the better answer generally.

Answer (score 2):

How about `foldLeft`:

```
val processed = stuff.foldLeft(List.empty[Thing]) { case (list, (label, value)) =>
  if (label.startsWith("!")) {
    list ++ (BigThing(label.tail, value) :: Bonus(label.tail) :: Nil)
  } else list :+ LittleThing(label,value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are already answers for the question, but if we notice the return type is `List[Product with Serializable]` because you try to create a list containing unrelated case classes and it is not coming into the best practice.

**Ex:**

```
scala> val processed = stuff.flatMap { case (label, value) =>
     |   if (label.startsWith("!"))
     |     List(BigThing(label.tail, value), Bonus(label.tail))
     |   else
     |     List(LittleThing(label, value))
     | }
processed: List[Product with Serializable] = List(BigThing(thing,value), Bonus(thing), LittleThing(otherthing,value))
```

We can remove it by providing return type explicitly. Since we are returning List of different case classes, we can use `Lis[Any]`.

**Ex:**

```
scala> trait Thing extends Product with Serializable
defined trait Thing

scala> case class BigThing(id: String, value: String) extends Thing
defined class BigThing

scala> case class Bonus(id: String) extends Thing
defined class Bonus

scala> case class LittleThing(id: String, value: String) extends Thing
defined class LittleThing

scala> val stuff = List( ("!thing","value"), ("otherthing","value") )
stuff: List[(String, String)] = List((!thing,value), (otherthing,value))

scala>  val result = stuff.flatMap { case (label, value) =>
     |         label match {
     |           case lable if label.startsWith("!") => List(BigThing(label.tail, value), Bonus(label.tail))
     |           case _ => List(LittleThing(label, value))
     |         }
     |       }
result: List[Thing] = List(BigThing(thing,value), Bonus(thing), LittleThing(otherthing,value))
```

Comment: These classes all extend the trait `Thing`, it makes more sense to inscript the return type as `List[Thing]`. Why don't you try that in the REPL and see what the return is without specifying the type